# ¿Como mejorar velocidad de esta consulta en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta que resulta muy lenta y quisisera ver como se puede mejorar.
Actualmente hay instalado un SQL SERVER 2008 R2 express edition
la consulta es esta

```
select top 9999999 
    albfacca.can,albfacca.ejealb,albfacca.numalb,albfacca.fecalb,
    clientes.nom,albfacca.suped,
    albfacca.totfac,
    albfacca.webnum,albfacca.actfac,albfacca.idrecno
    from albfacca
        left join clientes on clientes.codcli=albfacca.codcli   
    where 1=1  and albfacca.can='B '
order by fecalb DESC,ALBFACCA.IDRECNO DESC
```

La tabla albfacca tiene 94000 registros. 140 campos
La tabla clientes tiene 700 registros. 80 campos

las tablas estan correctamente indexadas.

esta consulta tarda mínimo 15 segundos

¿Se puede mejorar? ¿como?

Comment: Deberías añadir la estructura de todas estas tablas para que te podamos ayudar. De todos modos a primeras, el `where 1=1` es necesario? Siempre se va a cumplir esa condición y creo que se podría quitar.

Comment: `las tablas están correctamente indexadas`...puedes agregar el script de los índices y de creación de las tablas?

Comment: Usas esta consulta directamente o lo tienes como una vista?, lo pregunto por ese "hack" de usar `TOP ` con todas las filas para agregar un `ORDER BY` en una vista

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios.
- Decir que no se usa hay vista alguna creada.
- Esta consulta la monta un programa al entrar en una de sus opciones y la consulta sirve para mostrar los registros en una tabla.
- En principio diria que si estan correctamente indexadas, pero no descarto, que realmente no lo esté.
- ¿Como puedo compartir la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: @IcuScc Consultas el CREATE TABLE de la tabla y editas la pregunta añadiendo esos resultados, para saber la estructura que tienen las tablas y los indices, claves, etc..

Comment: @Marc pero si hago eso me salen un montón de filas. es que las tablas son kilometricas. Pego aquí todo el código que sale?

Comment: @IcuScc Tienes 2 opciones, pegar las tablas enteras, o sólo poner lo que es importante para que te podamos ayudar, es decir, poner cómo están creados los campos de las tablas que estas usando en ésta consulta, los índices que afectan a esos campos, keys, etc..